# Может у кого-то есть пример? ImageView в ListView

Tags: android, listview, java, bmp, потоки-данных

Уже который день пытаюсь реализовать что бы в **ImageView** который в **ListView** загружало картинки, но к успеху не привело. Пробовал много способов - без толку.
  Есть список, в нем по картинке, нужно загрузить туда эти картинки с сервера.

Делать это надо через **AsyncTask**, иначе - никак. Вся проблема в том, что в **doInBackGround** картинки нету**(img = null)**, а в **onPostExecute** есть, но забрать я ее оттуда не могу, не знаю как, и в интернете все что нашел, то ли с ошибками то ли не работает. Может у кого-то есть пример, или кто-то когда-то делал и скажет как хоть взять из **onPostExecute**, или вообще не нужно оттуда брать. Класс **AsyncTask** у меня отдельно и один.

Создает список а картинки нету, пустота...

Вот мой код:

```
                                    **Главная форма**
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static String q ="DEBUG";
   LoadDataTask ATK ;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> FeedList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
public void loadImage(View v) throws Exception{

    ATK = new LoadDataTask();
    setContentView(R.layout.feed);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = loadMyItems();
  Log.d(q,"MAP="+data.toString());
    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.feed,new String[] {"photo"},new int[] {R.id.imageView});
   lv.setAdapter(sa);
}

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> loadMyItems() {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            map.put("photo", ATK.execute("http://kocha.co/ziFzx").get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        };
        arrayList.add(map);
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

---

```
                                   **LoadDataTask.class**

public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    public static String q ="DEBUG";
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    }

    private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url) {
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: весь этот велосипед давно придуман за вас. Вам остается только использовать по инструкции. Обратите внимание на ответ @katso    
Мне лично больше нравится библиотека [Picasso][1]


  [1]: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из postExecute забрать загруженные данные можно по разному. Например, передавая в ваш AsynkTask класс ссылку на ImageView и в postExecute этому полю картинку и назначать.

Пример:

```
 public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        ImageView iv;

        //метод-конструктор, в коем сохраняем ссылку на переданное в класс ImageView
        public LoadDataTask (ImageView iv)
        {
            this.iv = iv;
        }

     @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) 
    {
        this.iv.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Соответственно вызывать:

```
LoadDataTask ATK = (LoadDataTask) new LoadDataTask((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView));
ATK.execute("YOUR_URL");
```

P.S.
Возможно вам будет удобнее со списком работать, создав отдельный класс-adapter.

Comment: Идея отличная, только будет 1 экземпляр ImageView, то есть, каждый раз работа с одним экземпляром, хоть картинок будет 15, загрузит только 15-ю и в 15-ю ячейку(

Comment: В своем приложении в данном случае я использую отдельный класс-адаптер, в коем получаю ссылки на каждую конкретную картинку для каждого конкретного пункта списка. Это очень удобно и не слишком сложно. Если хотите - могу выложить попозже отформатированный для простоты восприятия код.

Из преимуществ - любой дизайн пункта списка, манипуляций с его элементами; возможность использования разных layout для пунктов etc.
В принципе, в сети много примеров.

Answer (score 2):

**[UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)**

- асинхронная загрузка и отображение изображений из интернета или с SD-карты;
- возможность кэширования загруженных картинок в памяти и/или на файловой системе  - устройства;
- возможность отслеживания процесса загрузки посредством "слушателей"
- эффективная работа с памятью при кэшировании картинок в памяти;
- широкие возможности настройки инструмента под свои нужды.

[Подробное описание](http://nostra13android.blogspot.ru/2012/03/4-universal-image-loader-part-1.html)